# Meteor Angular, Ionic and Cordova, app in iOS simulator open to white screen

Tags: angularjs, cordova, meteor, angular-meteor

I am creating a new app with meteor angular, ionic and cordova.

I added platform iOS.

The app works perfectly fine in the browser

But when I do meteor run ios the iOS simulator opens to a white screen.

I inspected the dom in the simulator and noticed that angular has not bootstrapped.

I am using this code to bootstrap:

```
function onReady() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['ConnectedCar']);
  console.log('meteor is cordova');
}

if(Meteor.isCordova) {
  angular.element(document).on('deviceready', onReady);
} else {
  angular.element(document).ready(onReady);
}
```

I have placed this file in client/lib/app.js

Notice the log statement in the onReady function. It is run, so the angular bootstrap code is running.

But why is angular not working?

In my mobile-config.js I have `App.accessRule('*');`

In the console I do not see any errors that would signify angular not bootstrapping.

The only thing I notice is sometimes I get

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/297/cku0xuqw/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

Any idea why the app works perfectly fine in the browser, but not in the iOS simulator?